# Multiples frames are executed in the same browser thread?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, dom, browser

When you have a document in the browser, that load's one or more frames from the same origin server.

Those frames are executed by the same thread as the main window?

Or it's possible to have a frame with a heavy process and other frames won't freeze?

I haven't find any specification for that, someone know where is it if it exists?

Comment: I just make a test using Chrome with two frames, one with an endless javascript loop and another with a single form. I was able even to submit the form while the other frame was still computing. Hope it helps.

Comment: sure this is very helpful! I'm still searching in the web about it, javascript is single-thread, but the answers are changing along the time. ~ 2009 looks like your test would have another behavior. I supposed that behavior you test will occur, but I still don't know why and when it have been changed, and if has some doc for it.

Comment: But I think that this is a browser specific implementation. It is normal to render multiple frames it raises multiple threads (I hope). What do you think?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm no expert on "how browsers work" but what I predict is:

You cannot be sure. It depends on the type of engine (we talk about), browser and it's version...

If we are talking about the layout rendering engine (which is **generally** single threaded); everything is executed within a linear flow in a single thread. **Traditionally**, it was the main thread of the "**browser**", then with IE7 each browser "**window**" had its own thread. But it **keeps changing** in time and now it's mostly single thread per "**tab**".

Within a tab; while a javascript is executing, the rendering engine waits for it to finish. The reason is Javascript engines are **traditionally** sharing the same single thread (but not necessarily). Even, asynchronous events are queued for the appropriate time of execution.

Network operations on the other hand; are handled over multiple parallel threads. But again; callbacks of these operations are injected into browser's event loop in the main thread. (That's why the number of these calls are generally limited).

For rendering; inner/embedded frames (such as `iframe`) are subject to **Frame Constructor** (which is responsible for every rectangular box that has a size, padding, margin, position, etc). Script executions are handled in the same thread of the main window. (Again "**generally**" bec. in Opera this may not be the case if it is an iframe.)

So, each browser has an internal scheduling implementation for, when and how an event/operation will be queued and executed. For example; the image below demonstrates how a page request is handled in Gecko browsers.

[image]

The browser may decide whether to **postpone** a reflow or make it **immediate**. Generally the reason is to optimize the speed and painting but an immediate reflow is mostly a requirement. For example, a javascript code that alters the layout such as changing the height of a DOM element. This should be an immediate reflow so that the rendering engine can accurately calculate the bounds of the elements and continue the layout process. See [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZTnIxIA5KGw) about Gecko Reflow Visualization.

Back to your second question about non-freezing heavy processes:

In Opera, you might load a heavy process to an iframe and it may not block the main window. But this may also change in time. If you cannot get your hands on an API that promisses this; you cannot rely on it as non-blocking. As a developer you should think single threaded about Javascript and DOM operations.

What you can do is check out **Web Workers** in HTML5 spec. They can be accessed via javascript. I don't believe this brings multi-threading to javascript since workers can only talk to another thread via messages and do not have DOM access directly. But still, you can allocate a heavy calculation to a worker without disturbing the thread you're in.

### More resources:

- [Web Workers](http://dev.w3.org/html5/workers/)
- [Non-Blocking scripts](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/08/10/what-is-a-non-blocking-script/)
- [Frame Construction](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Gecko:Overview#Frame_Construction)
- [Layout in Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introduction_to_Layout_in_Mozilla#_Reflow_)

Comment: +1 your answer is very complete, I know about web workers, in this project they already are used, is about a mod webkit with some API that are only exported to the DOM, and can't be accessed by the worker, and run in a low hardware that take long some times to DOM persist. The hole idea is to trigger the custom API from another frame when main window is busy, or use a frame to never get the main window busy. I will do some experiments today with webkit, but I don't find a documentation that explains how this should work for major last versions of browser. Just a consensus for tabs threads.