# Does "Run-to-completion" apply to code inside an iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe

On an HTML5 game, I have a code that runs inside an iframe, the code has to run inside an iframe, so it's easy to run/kill/run without residues

The iframe code can modify the page variables with parent.* access

I'm wondering whether "Run-to-completion" applies to code inside the iframe too, whether the entire page's code, including iframes, actually runs in a single thread, or whether the parent.* access is unreliable, I've researched but couldn't find anything on the topic

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiples frames are executed in the same browser thread?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604834/multiples-frames-are-executed-in-the-same-browser-thread)

Comment: Also, a small test I made: https://jsfiddle.net/y7u5f7Lr/

Comment: @JacqueGoupil I like the idea, since there is no definite answer, experimentation will probably be the best answer, yet in your example, iframe always loads after all the wasteTime's have run, so probably a repetitive deadlock generator that both runs in the parent and iframe would give the answer for a specific browser, I'm yet to generate/test such a scenario

Answer (score 0):

It didn't occur to me to test this when I first asked the question, however, since a `while(1);` inside an iframe freezes the page, I'm assuming iframe javascript runs inside top's thread/context (or whatever the right term is) - At least this is the case for Chrome

Kind of explains how some earlier version of Adsense ads froze entire pages